# Will chester follow me through wormholes?

Tags: dont-starve

I'm playing Don't Starve and I jumped into a wormhole, after walk a little bit I found the "Eye Stick" (don't remember the real name) that makes Chester follow you.

Now I want to return to my camp base through the wormhole again, but I don't know if Chester will "jump with me" or be stuck where he is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Chester will follow you through the wormhole. Just be sure to keep the Eye Bone in your inventory. [[source](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Worm_Hole)]